# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: tn.hadoop.WordCount

Tags: java, hadoop, word-count

I'm using hadoop-2.6.0 in the same folder I created a new folder 'WordCount' in which I placed a WordCount.Class that contains the following code

```
package tn.hadoop;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.*;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {

 public static class Map extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String line = value.toString();
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line);
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            word.set(tokenizer.nextToken());
            context.write(word, one);
        }
    }
 } 

 public static class Reduce extends Reducer<Text, IntWritable, Text, IntWritable> {

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values, Context context) 
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        int sum = 0;
        for (IntWritable val : values) {
            sum += val.get();
        }
        context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
    }
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();

    Job job = new Job(conf, "WordCount");

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);

    job.setMapperClass(Map.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reduce.class);
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

    job.waitForCompletion(true);
 }

}
```

then I compressed this folder into .jar and executed the following command under hadoop-2.6.0

```
bin/hadoop jar WordCount.jar tn.hadoop.WordCount /home/hadoop/input/data.txt /home/hadoop/output
```

What's the problem in my code and command? please help

Comment: Quick note: please don't use the "code snippet" feature unless it's really Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this line at the proper location in driver class.

```
job.setJarByClass(Reduce.class);
```

Comment: I followed this link ,it helped me [link](https://portal.futuregrid.org/manual/hadoop-wordcount)